# Changing the Task Overdue email format in MOSS 2007 document approval workflow

Tags: sharepoint, alerts

How can I change the Email sent when a document in the out of the box document approval workflow is overdue.

The email I get is something like

---

Task assigned to Name here on 7/13/2009 is overdue. 
Due by 7/3/2009 
Please approve document1 From: Someone Sent: Monday, July 13, 2009 9:50 AM
To complete this task:
1.  Review Document.
2.  Perform the specific activities required for this task.
3.  Use the Edit this task button to mark the task as completed.

---

how can I change that? for example the "due by" be highlighted in red.

Answer (score 1):

There is some info here on customising alert templates:

http://blogs.msdn.com/sharepointdeveloperdocs/archive/2007/12/07/customizing-alert-notifications-and-alert-templates-in-windows-sharepoint-services-3-0.aspx

More detailed info here using INotificationEventHandler:

http://blogs.msdn.com/sharepointdeveloperdocs/archive/2007/12/14/how-to-customizing-alert-emails-using-ialertnotificationhandler.aspx

I think the Alert Template Name is SPAlertTemplateType.Tasks